# How Do you reset a bit value in a string?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In the recent interview I got a question like this :

`Given a string value, find out its 127th bit and reset it, do this in C language`
`Reset means if that particular bit is 0 change to 1 and vice versa`

I didn't find out any algorithm for this, but I want to know about how one could solve this in `C` language.

### Edit:

After getting the answer from few, I tried this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char *str="anto";
    str[15] ^= 0x80;
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

I get the output as : `anto`. Now I got strike in my head that changing a bit doesn't change the output?

Comment: Define "reset" a bit? (Set to 0?)

Comment: @Mysticial : Ya your correct, I have **edited** my question.

Comment: Please give a before and after example of how you expect this to behave, since bit numbering is somewhat arbitrary and it's not exactly clear what you mean by "string" in this context.

Comment: @PaulR : the same was to me :/ it was a written test and I have no one to clear my doubts. But I guess the question is to flip the bit, they need an algorithm for this.. Not an exact answer!

Comment: In your example, the 127th bit is way past 4 characters.

Comment: I thought reset means changing 1 to 0 and also 0 remains 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `char` is 8 bits and the endian is little-endian:

```
char *str = ...;

str[15] ^= 0x80;
```

This will flip the 127th bit.

EDIT:

If the bit-endian is big-endian, then use `0x01` instead.

The answer also depends on how the bits are numbered. If we start numbering from 0, the use `0x80`. If we index from 1, then we use `0x40`. (`0x01` and `0x02` for big-endian)

**EDIT 2 :
Here's the general case: (with the same assumptions)**

```
char *str = ...;
int bit = 127;

int index = bit / 8;   //  Get the index
int chbit = bit % 8;   //  Get which bit in the char

int mask = 1 << chbit; //  Build the mask

str[index] ^= mask;    //  XOR to flip the bit.
```

Comment: `^=` i guess this is `XOR`. But can you explain in detail? I'm very new to C. I can find what the first line is doing but not that second line.

Comment: For each bit, the XOR operator will return 0 if the bits are the same, and return 1 if they are different. So if you XOR against 1, you will flip the bit.

Comment: It depends on how you count bits of course, but I make that the 121st or the 128th bit (depends on what you consider to be the "first" bit in a byte), but its not the 127th bit.

Comment: Yeah, the endian is a little ambiguous here. If the endian is wrong, then, use `0x01` instead.

Comment: It's still not right - it needs to be 0x02 or 0x40 for 127th bit (count 'em !).

Comment: It depends on how we index the bits. If we start from index 0, then I think `0x80` or `0x01` is correct. (still cross-checking this in my head...)

Comment: Note that "127th bit" != "bit 127". The first bit would be bit 0, the second bit wound be bit 1, etc, so the Nth bit is bit N-1.

Comment: +1 for specifing ur logic with little endian...if possible also write for big-endian..!!!

Comment: @Mr. 32: Numbering of bits within a byte is not the same thing as endianness

Comment: @PaulR I have changed my question, can anyone clear that doubt even?

Answer (score 10):

To toggle any bit in a string:

```
#include <limits.h>

void flip_bit(char *x, int bit_no) {
  (x + bit_no/CHAR_BIT) ^= 1 << bit_no%CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Explanation:
Finding the bit_no:th bit is done in two steps:

First as many whole bytes as required (integer division):
    (x + bit_no/CHAR_BIT)

Then as many bits that are left over. This is done by shifting a 1 by
    bit_no%CHAR_BIT
bits (the remainder).

Finally toggle the bit using the xor operator (^).

Comment: seems to be very hard algorithm! Can you explain the line which is inside the `flip_bit` function?

Answer (score 0):

1st is you are asking is says as **toggle**  not **reset** okey

To toggle a bit

The XOR operator (^) can be used to toggle a bit.

```
 number ^= 1 << x;
```

That will toggle bit x.
 for more info of such think [read this](http://shareprogrammingtips.com/c-language-programming-tips/how-to-set-clear-toggle-and-check-a-single-bit-in-c/)

Now as you know string is number of character & size of 1 charachter is 1 byte so now which ever bit you want to toggle that put instead of X in and string in place of number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a bitmask, for the n-th bit, the bitmask will be:

```
char *bitmask = 2^(n-1);
```

and to flip the bit xor the string and the bitmask:

```
string ^= bitmask;
```