# Extracting specific bits from a bitstream, given a void pointer to the starting of the bitstream

Tags: c, bitmap, bit

I have a long bitstream and have a void pointer to the beginning of it. From this bitstream, I want to extract 'n' bits from bit position 'm'.

For example, I want to extract 75 bits from 57th bit position. How to do this?

I tried to do it by typecasting the void pointer into a char pointer and then increment it till m/8. From here on, I have no clue as to how to extract from here onwards.

How to work with such bitstreams in C?

Pardon me as I have not written any code here regarding approach because I don't know how to proceed and there is no better place to figure it out than here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! It is not a code writing service, you should tell what you have done so far, the problem you are facing and sample data.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is a question is about accessing specific bits through a char pointer. It doesn't answer your question but it may give you an idea on how to proceed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607224/how-do-you-reset-a-bit-value-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and non-optimized solution to extract from an array of bytes the `EXTRACT_COUNT` bits (here = 75) starting at `EXTRACT_OFFSET`(here = 57).

The `getBit()` returns (-1) when the requested `bitIndex` points out of the `bitArray[]`, otherwise it returns the value of the extracted bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getBit(unsigned char bitArray[], int lenArray,int bitIndex)
{
    int iBytePos = bitIndex >> 3;
    int iByteBit = bitIndex % 8;
    unsigned char uByteVal;

    if (iBytePos > lenArray) {
        return (-1);
    }
    uByteVal = bitArray[ iBytePos ];
    if (iByteBit==0) printf("."); // to mark the 8bits border
    if ((uByteVal & (0x80 >> iByteBit)) != 0) {
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE (18)
#define EXTRACT_OFFSET (57)
#define EXTRACT_COUNT  (75)

int main()
{
    unsigned char tabByte[ARRAY_SIZE] = {
        0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xA5, 0xFF,
        0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x00 };

    int iVal,iCount;

    iCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<EXTRACT_COUNT;i++)
    {
        iVal = getBit(tabByte,ARRAY_SIZE,i+EXTRACT_OFFSET);
        if (iVal >= 0) {
            iCount++;
            printf("%1d",iVal);
        }
    }
    printf("\niCount=%d\n",iCount);
    return (0);
}
```